# How can I fetch details from SharePoint list in infopath form from textbox

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-list, infopath-form

I am creating a infopath form where ID textbox gets populated from the query string. Now the problem I am facing is, I am not able to fetch and populate the remaining textboxes such as "**UserName**", "**FirstName**", "**Address**", "**Block No**" from the sharepoint list based on the **ID** textbox that gets populated from query string.

I have googled around the internet, but I am not able to understand the procedure to get the desired result. Also fetching of the details are done on the dropdown and not on the textbox.

Since I am new to infopath form designing. I am not able to find the proper methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create datasource to the library/list, filter data by your ID, get values from it.

[Here is example with getting data from SP list](https://wonderlaura.com/2011/08/01/infopath-query-specific-sharepoint-list-data/comment-page-1/)

[HERE is article about it.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/05/06/sharepoint-list-data-connections-in-infopath-2010/)
[HERE is example but with User Profile](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/) (you will do the same, connection to library, set value of InfoPath fields with value from DataSource, filtered by ID.

Comment: Do you have any steps or procedure/link for the same ?

Comment: Edited an answer.